# Mobile theme switching problems

Tags: themes, mobile

I am trying to setup my site to enable a responsive mobile device layout. I can't update my whole site to use a different theme so have decided to add another them which I will only show on mobile devices. To switch between them I have added the any mobile theme switcher.

I am having a problem getting this to work. On some of the themes I tried, if it wasn't the active theme, it wouldn't display correctly. I have found a theme which still looks ok but the menu dropdown button doesn't work unless it is set as the active theme.

Is there something causing the non active themes to lose functionality?

Comment: In all honesty, stay with responsive design. Mobile theme switchers are a thing of the past and a lot of crap in my opinion as there is no reliable way in php to detect devices

Comment: It detects the devices just fine. The issue is that the theme that's not set as active is not working correctly.